# refresh Camera.names in actionscript

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, camera

In actioscript I can get the user cameras from Camera.names.
It works find but sometimes users connect the camera only after the app is started.
When the app is already running it doesn't update the list of Camera.names when connecting or disconnecting a camera.

Is there a way to update the Camera.names list?

Thanks

Comment: If someone is interested in this feature, please vote on the following issue https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3327544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is something that's not possible to 'bind' since when the call for the Camera names is done, the Flash Player doesn't get a 'notice' of the new connection.

What I have done in the past is have something poll Camera.names every minute *or* have a 'refresh' button next to the list for when the user does add a camera.

In your case, it seems to have a polling mechanism is the better approach (depending on your UI of course).

Comment: The problem is that Flash Player doesn't read the hardware again if it see at least one camera. I couldn't find any way to force it to read the hardware again.